# Qt, Открыть окно в другом thread

Tags: c++, qt

В главном окне программы обрабатываются изображения, пока идет обработка надо вывести окно, не мешая обработке. Как это сделать?

Comment: Окно не прорисуется пока не закончится работа в главном окне

Comment: Интерфейс может показываться только в основном потоке, для такой задачи надо длинные действия уносить в отдельный поток. То, что вы спрашиваете, сделать нельзя.